# My anko-sqlite database object can't be called

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

So here's my database helper code

```
class DatabaseHelper(ctx: Context) : ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(ctx, "FavoriteMatch.db", null, 1){

    companion object {
        private var instance: DatabaseHelper? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(ctx: Context): DatabaseHelper {
            return instance ?: DatabaseHelper(ctx.applicationContext)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.createTable(Favorite.TABLE_FAVORITE, true,
            Favorite.MATCH_ID to TEXT + PRIMARY_KEY,
            Favorite.TEAM_HOME_NAME to TEXT,
            Favorite.TEAM_HOME_GOAL to INTEGER,
            Favorite.TEAM_AWAY_NAME to TEXT,
            Favorite.TEAM_AWAY_GOAL to INTEGER,
            Favorite.EVENT_DATE to TEXT,
            Favorite.EVENT_TIME to TEXT)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
        db.dropTable(Favorite.TABLE_FAVORITE, true)
    }

    val Context.database : DatabaseHelper
        get() = getInstance(applicationContext)
}
```

here's the favorite data class

```
data class Favorite(
    val idEvent: String?,
    val strHomeTeam: String?,
    val strAwayTeam: String?,
    val strHomeGoalDetails: String?,
    val strAwayGoalDetails: String?,
    val dateEvent: String?,
    val strTime: String?
) {
    companion object {
        const val TABLE_FAVORITE: String = "TABLE_FAVORITE"
        const val MATCH_ID: String = "ID_"
        const val TEAM_HOME_NAME: String = "HOME_NAME"
        const val TEAM_HOME_GOAL: String = "HOME_GOAL"
        const val TEAM_AWAY_NAME: String = "AWAY_NAME"
        const val TEAM_AWAY_GOAL: String = "AWAY GOAL"
        const val EVENT_DATE: String = "DATE_EVENT"
        const val EVENT_TIME: String = "EVENT_TIME"
    }
}
```

but somehow i can't call my database instance from database helper anywhere, for example, i called it in my ScheduleDetailActity.kt, there is no database object
[image]

the goal is that this database can be called like this

```
database.use {
   //Insert to database
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context.database should be defined outside the `DatabaseHelper` scope. So your `DatabaseHelper` should look like following

```
 class DatabaseHelper(ctx: Context) : ManagedSQLiteOpenHelper(ctx, "FavoriteMatch.db", null, 1){

   // Your previous code 

}

val Context.database : DatabaseHelper
    get() = getInstance(applicationContext)
```